# Alinhar itens do Menu Verticalmente

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando criar um menu horizontal mas estou com dificuldades no alinhamento vertical.

Alguns itens do menu possuem quebra de linha e outros não.

Tentei criar um CSS para configurar os elementos `div`, `ul` e `li` para que fiquem alinhados no centro verticalmente, mas os itens que não possuem quebra de linha, ficam alinhados na base dos itens que possuem quebra de linhas.

Fiz um exemplo no Fiddle e gostaria da ajuda de vocês: [Código no Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisSoares/q9jkqkww/)

```css
#menu{
  background: #535454;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li a{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
  color: #333333;
  background: #00a4e6;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Proteção para Cabeça</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Luvas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Proteção para Torax</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Botas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Proteção para Pernas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Usando vertical-align:

Faltou o `vertical-align` no seu código. Por padrão, `inline-block` é alinhado pelo `baseline`.

Veja com `vertical-align:middle`:

```css
#menu{
  background: #535454;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li a{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
  color: #333333;
  background: #00a4e6;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Proteção para Cabeça</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Luvas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Proteção para Torax</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Botas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Proteção para Pernas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Só pra constar, se fosse alinhar por cima, seria `vertical-align:top`. Talvez fosse melhor já usar o `<ul>` como `#menu`, para simplificar o código.

Comment: Porque o hover dos itens de uma linha não preenchem o espaço todo?

Comment: @DiegoF pq um inline-block é como se fosse um caractere de texto normal. Não é adequado pra esse tipo de menu. Eu provavelmente nem usaria `ul` pra um layout desse tipo, mas sabe como são as tais "boas práticas" né :)

Comment: @Bacco obrigado pela dica! Agora, como resolver o problema do hover dos itens de uma linha, que o DiegoF mencionou, para ocuparem todo o espaço da ul ?

Comment: @ChristianoRibeiroSoares é como eu comentei, o inline-block não é pra esse tipo de coisa. Provavelmente o melhor seria trocar por flexbox, ou coisa do tipo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode alinhar texto verticalmente alterando o `display` para `table-cell` com `vertical-align:middle;` e para que isso funcione a mesma precisa estar dentro de uma div com `display:table;`. Essa é apenas uma das formas.

```css
#menu{
  background: #535454;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: table;
}

#menu ul li{
  display: table-cell;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#menu ul li a{
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li:hover{
  color: #333333;
  background: #00a4e6;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Proteção para Cabeça</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Luvas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Proteção para Torax</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Botas</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Proteção para Pernas</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```